# What is an animated surface mesh?

Tags: animation, opengl, 3d

What is an animated surface mesh? What kind of file format do animated surface meshes have on the disk?

I am reading the paper [Animated Mesh Approximation With Sphere-Meshes](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~boubek/papers/ASM/) . The input of the algorithm mentioned in the paper is an animated surface mesh. But I do not know what is an animated surface mesh. I just learn a little about surface mesh, which may be an .off file on the disk.

A snapshot is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3pqs.png)

Comment: Whatever it is, it has nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Animated Surface Mesh file contains a sequence of mesh information, usually  mesh deformation information for each frame. Best example is MD3 file format.

The paper you are referring to, is trying to convert animated mesh file into a skeletal animation format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got a good answer to this question from https://www.zhihu.com/question/50173048?from=profile_question_card.

The paper says:

> Problem statement. We aim at approximating a mesh animation
>   with F frames, (meaning F different triangles meshes having
>   the same connectivity) with an animated sphere-mesh (a mesh
>   where each vertex is associated with a time-varying sphere).

So the animated surface mesh is a mesh animation with F frames.Every frame is a mesh with same connectivity.

And the horse models in the paper can be got from here: http://people.csail.mit.edu/sumner/research/deftransfer/data.html. 
And other models(eg:Capoeira，Samba) can be got from http[:]//people.csail.mit.edu/drdaniel/mesh_animation/

Thanks Xia Qing again.

原作者：夏清
来源：知乎
著作权归作者所有，转载请联系作者获得授权。